# About SQL Server IF clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a question about SQL Server's `IF` clause.

For example - look at this code:

```
IF (@logpath IS NOT NULL || @ptd IS NOT NULL)
```

Can I use `||` in the condition when I use `IF` statement?

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

|| is not valid Transact-SQL syntax. You need to user 'OR' or 'AND'

Example

```
IF @logpath is not null OR @ptd is not null
  BEGIN
  -- do something 
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `||` operator in SQL Server. Please refer the following link which shows the list of logical operators in SQL Server

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189773.aspx